# show mapped drive as shared folder

Tags: network-share, mappeddrive

I have a mapped network drive and backup folder inside it.

[O:\Backup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnVrS.png)

But I can't share this folder like **\\localhost\backup**

Is there a way to share a folder in a mapped drive?

Comment: It's obviously already shared on the host server. Why do you need to share it again?

Comment: 'Cause the backup software does not accept map network drive.

Comment: If it will only connect to a UNC path then point it at the UNC path of the shared folder on the server hosting the shared folder. I'm not understanding the difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. The mapped network drive belongs to a different machine, and as such only that machine can share it. It's likely a matter of controlling who is allowed to view that drive's content - if you were allowed to share a drive, the owner of that drive would basically lose control over permissions to that share. Or at least I believe that is the logic involved.